# How to get "drop down button" size of ComboBox in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How can I get the size of the `DropDown Button` on a `ComboBox`?

For anyone unsure of what I mean, it is the `Button` usually found on the right hand side of a `ComboBox` containing a downward facing arrow. When clicked this expands the `DropDown` section.

For further clarification, it is the button in the red circle in the below image.

[image]

Comment: _I want to get drop down button size of the combbox_ What is that mean?

Comment: @Soner Gönül the size(width) of the button placed on right side of combobox

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For such constants you can use [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) API function; C# quick analogue is [SystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  ...

  int arrowWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
```

Comment: Ohkk. This worked successfully. It is the right solution, what i am looking for. It is amazing fact that the combobox button is same as the vertical scroll bar arrow button. Thanx to @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: The SystemInformation class is also accessible in C++/CLI